# How to use NSURLsession and its delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

My app running is using `NSURLConnection`. But now want to change it completely to 
`NSURLsession`. Saw lots of tutorials but I can't understand how to use the delegate methods. Please, can any one explain properly that `NSURLsession` and the delegate methods.

> http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising

This is a sampl url. how can I parse and get the response using `NSURLsession`.
New in development. Thanks advance.

Comment: can you show ur tried code , it does not a problem if it is wrong also

Comment: see lot of tutorial.Use this link to develop  https://ktrkathir.wordpress.com/2015/10/16/how-to-use-nsurlsession-delegates-to-download-a-nsdata-in-ios/comment-page-1/#comment-199. Here can't i find network loss delegate. this code only work  this  method.if i remove this not working. dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                                      {
                                          
                                     });  can't under properly.

Comment: any wrong in my link..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**YOU CAN DO LIKE THIS:**

```
//GET REQUEST CODE
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    // NSURLSession *s = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"PUT_YOUR_URL"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        //
        if (data) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse  = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
            if (statusCode == 200) {
               //PERFORM YOUR OPERATIONS
            }
        }else if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Errorrrrrrr....");
        }

    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

Comment: sorry i want in obj c

Comment: In NsurlConnection we use the delegate method. 1.didReceiveResponse 2.didReceiveData 3.didFailWithError 4.connectionDidFinishLoading. Here Nsurlsession what are delegate how to use?

Comment: You will get your data in the completion handler. As you can see in my answer,  dataTaskWithRequest completion handler has NSData which the data returned after hitting the URL.

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising this url in this code but not get response.

Comment: You will have to append "http" protocol at the start of your URL .  But this will give you error like App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP  For that you will have to set App Transport Security.You can get its answer easily on stackoverflow. For temporary testing  you can use "https" protocol.

Comment: Add these are delegate methods for NSUrlSession 1.-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data; 2.-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler; 3.-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error;

Comment: No App Transport Security fix that issue. want to know to use above nsurl session delegate method with my url and ur code help me...

Comment: @saravanar I think I have provided you everything about NSUrlSession and its delegate methods. You just have to try yourself now.Why don't you try and then show us where are you facing problem?

Comment: https://ktrkathir.wordpress.com/2015/10/16/how-to-use-nsurlsession-delegates-to-download-a-nsdata-in-ios/comment-page-1/#comment-199
use link and i try it. i dnt know what wrong in this link. show any proper link to learn and try ole

Comment: try this https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/. And if I have solved your problem then please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask=[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=apple&media=software"] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",json);
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
```

**Delegate Methods:**

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.progress.hidden=YES;
        self.image.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
    [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
}
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes
{

}
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    float progress=(double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.progress setProgress:progress];
    });
}
```

Comment: Here network loss means with delegate method can i use help me.